# Using Hamcrest's hasKeyValuePair with laravel's unit test

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, hamcrest, mockery

I have the following test:

```
public function testTestNameRequired(){
    Validator::shouldReceive("make")->once()
        ->with(array(1,2,3), hasKeyValuePair("name",array("required")))
        ->andReturn(m::mock(["passes"=>true]));

    $r = $this->vendorRepo->test(array(1,2,3));
    assertThat($r,is(TRUE));
}
```

When I run this test, I get the following error:

```
1) VendorRepoTest::testTestNameRequired
    Mockery\Exception\NoMatchingExpectationException: No matching handler found for Illuminate\Validation\Factory::make(Array, Array). Either the method was unexpected or its arguments matched no expected argument list for this method
```

Hamcrest is obviously installed because the test doesn't whine about not knowing what `hasKeyValuePair()` is. But I guess it isn't doing what I think it should. I rewrote it to use Hamcrest's `anything()` method like this:

```
public function _testTestFieldRequired($field){
    Validator::shouldReceive("make")->once()
        ->with(array(1,2,3), anything()) //hasKeyValuePair($field,array("required")))
        ->andReturn(m::mock(["passes"=>true]));

    $r = $this->vendorRepo->test(array(1,2,3));
    assertThat($r,is(TRUE));
}
```

and I get the same error. However, using `Mockery::any()` works:

```
public function _testTestFieldRequired($field){
    Validator::shouldReceive("make")->once()
        ->with(array(1,2,3), Mockery::any()) //hasKeyValuePair($field,array("required")))
        ->andReturn(m::mock(["passes"=>true]));

    $r = $this->vendorRepo->test(array(1,2,3));
    assertThat($r,is(TRUE));
}
```

I'm thinking that I don't have Mockery or Hamcrest installed correctly. They aren't playing well together. Here is my composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.0.*",
        "way/generators": "dev-master",
        "zurb/foundation": "v4.3.1",
        "intervention/image": "dev-master",
        "intervention/helper": "dev-master"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "mockery/mockery": "dev-master@dev",
        "cordoval/hamcrest-php": "dev-master@dev",
        "way/laravel-test-helpers": "dev-master",
        "loic-sharma/profiler": "dev-master"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php",
            "app/OfficePilot"
        ],
        "files": [
            "vendor/cordoval/hamcrest-php/hamcrest/Hamcrest.php"

        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "pre-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, it appears to be isolated to the cordoval/hamcrest-php package.

I have switched to the davedevelopment/hamcrest-php package to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Now the repository has officially moved to https://packagist.org/packages/hamcrest/hamcrest-php. You can use v1.0.0 as a dependency to be compatible with latest Mockery version.

There is a PR https://github.com/padraic/mockery/pull/170 that updates Mockery code to be compatible with Hamcrest v1.1.0 release, that is using namespaces instead of global matcher functions.